# Android phone screen position finding

Tags: android, android-screen

I am facing a challenge in my new application, i want to find the android phone screen facing ceiling or floor.Can i able to make this with the android sensors.If any body tried this please share your valuable ideas and tutorial if available.

Comment: and why has this been upvoted twice ?

Comment: @njzk2 DO you have solution for this question

Comment: yes. but this has been asked many times, there are tons of sensors tutorials, including on the android dev homepage, so I don't see the point of A/ adding yet another question, B/ more importantly adding yet another answer

Comment: Any way you people are trying hard to help me.. Thanks a lot and +1 for all help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `oncreate`

```
    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    List<Sensor> sensorList = sensorManager
            .getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    if (sensorList.size() > 0) {
        accelerometerPresent = true;
        accelerometerSensor = sensorList.get(0);
    }
```

register the `SensorEventListener`

```
        sensorManager.registerListener(accelerometerListener,
                accelerometerSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
```

and the `SensorEventListener` implementation

```
private SensorEventListener accelerometerListener = new SensorEventListener() {

    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {            
    }

    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        float z_value = event.values[2];
        if (z_value == 10) {
            // up facing
        } else if(z_value == -10)
            // down facing
        }           
    }
};
```

In my two device it shows z_values = 10 when it is upfacing and horizontal and in the opposite case it is showing - 10. check your cases.

Comment: How you can say with the z value the phone screen is facing floor.I think we can only get the up and down motion of a phone from your answer.

Comment: do you wan to detect exactly when the device is horizontal to the ground? in my answer when the device screen is moved to downwar or upward that will be detected

Comment: see my updated answer .. I used first part in my project .. and second part is collected from so answers so check whether it works for you

Comment: can you able to give a little bit explanation of your modified answer

Comment: just tested.. modifying the answer again .. for further comment pls test the code

Comment: do u ever tried to find the left right motion of a android phone

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `SensorEventListener` to achieve this. Have a look at my below code for a better understanding. You can also look at [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html) in the developer docs for more about sensors.

```
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;

public class SensorClass implements SensorEventListener {
    private float   mInR[];
    private float   mI[];
    private float   mGravity[];
    private float   mGeomag[];
    private float   mOrientVals[];

    final float rad2deg = 180/((float) Math.PI);

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // Do something here when accuracy changed
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        float azimuth = 0f;
        float pitch = 0f;
        float roll = 0f;

        // If the sensor data is unreliable return
        if (event.accuracy == SensorManager.SENSOR_STATUS_UNRELIABLE)
            return;

        // Gets the value of the sensor that has been changed
        switch (event.sensor.getType()){  
        case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
            mGravity = event.values.clone();
            break;
        case Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD:
            mGeomag = event.values.clone();
            break;
        }

         if (mGravity != null && mGeomag != null){
            // checks that the rotation matrix is found
            if (SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(mInR, mI, mGravity, mGeomag)){

                // magnetic north and the horizon respectively
                SensorManager.getOrientation(mInR, mOrientVals);

                azimuth = mOrientVals[0]*rad2deg;
                pitch = mOrientVals[1]*rad2deg;
                roll = mOrientVals[2]*rad2deg;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou @Neil and in this which one gives me when phone screen is down and up.Can you give a sample for the case if the screen is down what happen to these three values

Comment: You will have to use a combination of roll and pitch. When you use pitch the value of pitch should be 0 then the phone is level. Roll value will be 0 if the phone is facing up and < than -170 if the phone is facing down. Use logs to print out the values

Comment: yes i am doing the same way but the  same values can be happen if the phone moves to the left side or right side(I mean the same values can be repeated in different condition)

Comment: No the values change if you are tilting to the left or the right. You get different degrees. Did you test my code?

Comment: i have wrote the same code.Any way will come with the log to verify